# Center a string using sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I have a code that would like to display the message in the center between the bars. I looked at the C functions and found nothing that would allow me this.

```
sprintf(message,"============================================================");
send_message(RED, message);
sprintf(message, "[ Welcome %s ]", p->client_name);
send_message(RED, message);
sprintf(message,"============================================================");
send_message(RED, message);
```

I am looking for a way to show the Welcome message by counting the size of the user name always show centralized. Example:

example 1:

```
=============================================
                Welcome Carol                
=============================================
```

example 2:

```
=============================================
               Welcome Giovanna               
=============================================
```

Comment: There is no explicit command. Just count the number of letters in the text and the bar, build the difference, divide by two and prepend that amount of spaces.

Comment: @koalo but how am I going to count the bars and apply on the name message? could you give an example?

Comment: Your bars consist of 45 = if I count correctly. In the Giovanni example, the message has 16 characters. 45-16=29. 29/2=14.5, so left of the message should be 14 or 15 spaces.

Comment: I agree with @koalo, but it needs a bit work further..Can you see my answer and tell me your opinion? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special function for it, so you should do the math.

- Count the number of bars, and the length of the message.
- Subtract them and divide by 2.
- If the length of the message is even, then add 1 to the quotient.
- Add to the quotient the length of the message.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* message = "Welcome Giovanna";
    int len = (int)strlen(message);
    printf("===============================================\n"); // 45 chars
    printf("%*s\n", (45-len)/2 + ((len % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0) + len, message);
    printf("===============================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
=============================================
               Welcome Giovanna               
=============================================
```

---

PS: You could replace `(45-len)/2 + ((len % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0)` with `(46-len)/2`, in order to get the same result, since the latter is shorter.

Comment: the name is pulled using **p->client_name** how will I do to recognize the size of the name?

Comment: why to add one if `len % 2 == 0` ???? anyway, the same result can be obtained simply substituting the whole expression with `(46 - len)/2`

Comment: In order to center the name @LuisColorado. Indeed, you are right, answer updated!