# warning: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'}

Tags: c, string, printf, format-specifiers, size-t

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 2;
    printf("%*s\n", strlen("foo") + number, "foo");
    return 0;
}
```

Warning:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:14: warning: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
     printf("%*s\n", strlen("foo") + number, "foo");
             ~^~     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is it possible to eliminate this warning without casting the result of `strlen()` to an `int`, while keeping the width specifier as a variable? If yes, how?

Comment: No, printf expects an int for `*` , so just give it an int.-->> cast it to int. : `(int)(strlen("foo") + 2)`

Comment: Yes @wildplasser, this is what I conclude in too, but I asked because I might be wrong..Maybe there is something else than the star that I can use..Hmm...

Comment: `printf("  %s\n",  "foo");` is simpler, IMHO.(or even : `printf("  foo\n");`  )

Comment: But how would I pass a width variable then @wildplasser, seems like casting is the way to go.

Comment: Your  expression is a constant , not a variable.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity @wildplasser, however, I updated my answer to be exact. Thanks!

Comment: Because I thought I was using the wrong operator, and by using casting, I would be cutting corners @usr. The actual problem is this, and the inspiration is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730556/center-a-string-using-sprintf). BTW, if you are the downvoter, then please tell me what's wrong with my question, I beg you. If there is something wrong, I should improve it.

Comment: @usr you are wrong! I searched before posting, but didn't write the lame stuff some people write "I have searched for X time, but couldn't find anything..". I show the links you post. However, I thought that I *might be wrong*, thus decided to ask! If my question deserves a downvote (that was the research done, the minimal example and is exact), then I wonder how much a negative score you should put in the bad questions. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf expects an int for `*` , so just give it an int.-->> cast it to int.

---

```
printf("%*s\n", (int)(strlen("foo")+number), "foo");
```

---

But if you want to avoid the cast, you could use a variable for the length argument:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 2;
    int fmtlen;

    fmtlen = strlen("foo") + number;
    printf("%*s\n", fmtlen, "foo");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: the correct types are essential for `printf()`s arguments, since it is a varargs function: the only way for printf to determine the types of its arguments is by inpecting the format string. And `*` expects an int.

Comment: OP wanted to *avoid* casting. Assigning to a variable with the correct (int) type, and using this as an argument for printf is definitely an answer to this question.